# How to repeat a choice prompt in Microsoft Bot for Teams?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a Microsoft Teams Bot created using NodeJS for user to get some data using a Dialog flow.

```
constructor(id) {
    super(id);

    this.addDialog(
        new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.getData1.bind(this),
            this.getChoice.bind(this),
            this.getData2.bind(this),
        ])
    )
    .addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT))
    .addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT));

    this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;
}
```

```
async getData1(stepContext) {
    if (stepContext.context.activity.text) {
        var name = stepContext.context.activity.text;
        var result =  await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '<apiUrl>',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            var cardButtons = [];
            var cardText = "";
                
            if (data.length > 0) {
                data.forEach(element => {
                    cardButtons.push({
                        type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
                        title: element.name,
                        value: element.name
                    });
                });
                cardText = "Data for " + name  + ".";
           } else {
               cardText = "No Data Found.";
               cardButtons = null;
           }
           var dataCard = CardFactory.heroCard("Data-I", null, cardButtons, {
               text: cardText
            });
            return dataCard;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error > " + error);
        });
        if (result) {
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity({attachments: [result]});
        } else {
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong. Please try again.");
            return await stepContext.endDialog();
        }
        const messageText = 'Select/Enter Data to View.';
        const msg = MessageFactory.text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
        return await stepContext.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, { prompt: msg });
    } else {
        await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong. Please try again.");
        return await stepContext.endDialog();
    }
}
```

```
async getChoice(stepContext) {
    return await stepContext.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
        prompt: 'Please select the data2 options.',
        choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C', 'Option D']),
        style: ListStyle.heroCard
    });
}
```

```
async getData2(stepContext) {
    var dataChoice = null;
    if (stepContext.result) {
        dataChoice = stepContext.result
    }
    var result =  await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: '<data2apiUrl>',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'dataChoice': dataChoice
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data;
        console.log("Data KPI > ", JSON.stringify(data));
        var body = [];

        if (data.length > 0) {
            data.forEach(element => {
                var header = {
                    "type": "Container",
                    "spacing": "medium",
                    "style": "emphasis",
                    "verticalContentAlignment": "center",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": element.fullTitle,
                            "size": "medium",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "wrap": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
                body.push(body);
            });
        } else {
            //Recall the Choice Prompt
        }

        var dataCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.0",
            "body": body
        });
        return dataCard;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error > " + error);
    });
    if (result) {
        await stepContext.context.sendActivity({attachments: [result]});
    } else {
        await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong. Please try again.");
    }
    return await stepContext.endDialog();
 }
```

So this is the dialog flow I have. Now at `getChoice(stepContext)`,if I select a choice for which I don't have any data, I want the bot to call the `getChoice(stepContext)` step again instead of having to use `stepContext.endDialog()` and repeat the whole thing again from the first step of the dialog flow i.e `getData1(stepContext)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Validators**. check out this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/3c447befefdd4b049f4f3b5d32c726f94ecc4fe3/samples/javascript_nodejs/81.skills-skilldialog/dialogRootBot/dialogs/mainDialog.js#L41).

`.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(SKILL_ACTION_PROMPT, this.skillActionPromptValidator))`

```
/**
* This validator defaults to Message if the user doesn't select an existing option.
*/
 async skillActionPromptValidator(promptContext) {
    if (!promptContext.recognized.succeeded) {
        promptContext.recognized.value = { value: SKILL_ACTION_MESSAGE };
    }

    return true;
}
```

Have a look at the doc showing [ChoicePrompt validators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/choiceprompt?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#ChoicePrompt_string__PromptValidator_FoundChoice___string__ChoiceDefaultsChoicePrompt_).

> Validator that will be called each time the user responds to the
> prompt. If the validator replies with a message no additional retry
> prompt will be sent

Comment: I am not looking at whether user selects the valid option. Given it's guaranteed that user will definitely select one of the options provided, I want if the option user selected has no data via the API call in the `getData2()` step, I want the `ChoicePrompt` to be shown again to the user.

Comment: It seems like you can move code from getData2 into validator if you it has some data then you proceed ahead.

Comment: I have created a new Waterfall Dialog with the `getChoice()` and the `getData2()` as the steps in the waterfall. It's working for me.
Thanks for this help though, will keep in mind if I face a similar issue.

Comment: Oh Amazing. Thanks for sharing.